# How to adjust the threshold for template matching in openCV (java)?

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I am running template matching using openCV 3.4.7 Android SDK (java).
The code work almost perfectly; when the template is match, it draws a rectangle on the matching area. The problem is that even when there is no match, it draws a random rectangle. I think that happens because the threshold is not set correctly. If so, can someone please help me out?

Here's the code:

```
public static void run(String inFile, String templateFile, String outFile,
                    int match_method) {
        Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(inFile);
        Mat templ = Imgcodecs.imread(templateFile);

        // / Create the result matrix
        int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
        int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
        Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

        // / Do the Matching and Normalize
        Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
        Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

        // / Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
        Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);

        Point matchLoc;
        if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF
                || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
            matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
        } else {
            matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
        }

        // / Show me what you got
        Imgproc.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
                matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 0, 128));

        // Save the visualized detection.
        System.out.println("Writing " + outFile);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(outFile, img);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED or Imgproc.TM_CCORR_NORMED and mmr.maxVal >= 0.8. It should take care of most of your false positives.

Sample Code:

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class templateMatchingTester {

    private static String str = null;

    static {
        if (str == null) {
            str = "initialised";
            nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();
            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        }

    }

    private static Mat createMatrixFromImage(String imagePath) {
        Mat imageMatrix = Imgcodecs.imread(imagePath);
        Mat greyImage = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(imageMatrix, greyImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        return greyImage;
    }

    private static boolean matchTemplate(String pathToInputImage,String pathToTemplate){

        Mat inputImage = createMatrixFromImage(pathToInputImage);
        Mat templateImage = createMatrixFromImage(pathToTemplate);

        // Create the result matrix
        int result_cols = inputImage.cols() - templateImage.cols() + 1;
        int result_rows = inputImage.rows() - templateImage.rows() + 1;
        Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        int match_method;
        match_method = Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED;//Imgproc.TM_CCORR_NORMED;
        Imgproc.matchTemplate(inputImage, templateImage, result, match_method);
        Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);
        double minMatchQuality = 0.85; 
        System.out.println(mmr.maxVal);
        if (mmr.maxVal >= minMatchQuality){
            return true;
        } else
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String template = "path/to/your/templateImage";
        final File folder = new File("path/to/your/testImagesFolder/");
        int matchCount = 0;
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()){
            if (matchTemplate(fileEntry.getPath(),template)){
                matchCount+=1;
            }else
                System.out.println(fileEntry.getPath());
        }
        System.out.println(matchCount);

    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried  but sadly with no success because I always get all results 1.0 or really near the 1.0, making impossible to discard false positives.

Comment: can you share your template, a positive image and a negative sample?

Comment: @Piglet Please check the above link for the template and images.

Comment: @DeborahAnn I tried template matching on all the images you shared, I didnot get any false results at all. Note: I was using  Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED with a threshold of 0.85. Could you try the same and revert back with your findings.

Comment: @ShubhamJaiswal can you please share the complete code? I remember trying with TM_CCOEFF_NORMED and getting always 1.0

Answer (score 1):

Use a normed match method to ensure your match value is [0..1].

Replace this line

```
Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
```

with a thresholding operation. Otherwise a best match of 0.9 would become 1 by the second normalization and you would lose the actual match "quality" information.

Normalizing the result of the template matching will always result in your best match being 1 making it impossible to discard a bad match.

Comment: I am not normalizing the result as you suggested and have set a threshold checking the mmr.maxVal (I am suing TM_CCOEFF). Even though I have removed many of false positives, I have still a few false positives. Sadly if I increase the threshold it happens that I discard correct matches.

Comment: @DeborahAnn if you cannot get rid of false positives using a global threshold you have multiple things that match as well as the thing you're looking for. then you need another approach.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote an app that would take a screenshot of the game overwatch and attempt to tell who is on each team. using template matching and open cv. [project](https://github.com/mavriksc/overcomp) need to iterate over the result image and check values.

`OpenCVUtils.getPointsFromMatAboveThreshold(result, 
0.90f)`

```
public static void scaleAndCheckAll(String guid){       
    Mat source = imread(IMG_PROC_PATH + guid);  //load the source image
    Mat scaledSrc = new Mat(defaultScreenshotSize, source.type());
    resize(source, scaledSrc, defaultScreenshotSize);
    Mat sourceGrey = new Mat(scaledSrc.size(), CV_8UC1);
    cvtColor(scaledSrc, sourceGrey, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);        

    for (String hero : getCharacters()) {
        Mat template = OpenCVUtils.matFromJar(TEMPLATES_FOLDER + hero + ".png", 0); //load a template
        Size size = new Size(sourceGrey.cols()-template.cols()+1, sourceGrey.rows()-template.rows()+1);
        Mat result = new Mat(size, CV_32FC1);
        matchTemplate(sourceGrey, template, result, TM_CCORR_NORMED);// get results
        Scalar color =  OpenCVUtils.randColor();
        List<Point> points = OpenCVUtils.getPointsFromMatAboveThreshold(result, 
0.90f);
        for (Point point : points) {
            //rectangle(scaledSrc, new Rect(point.x(),point.y(),template.cols(),template.rows()), color, -2, 0, 0);
            putText(scaledSrc, hero, point, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, color);
        }
    }
    String withExt = IMG_PROC_PATH + guid +".png";
    imwrite(withExt,  scaledSrc);
    File noExt = new File(IMG_PROC_PATH + guid);
    File ext = new File(withExt);
    noExt.delete();
    ext.renameTo(noExt);                
}
```

the other method.

```
public static List<Point> getPointsFromMatAboveThreshold(Mat m, float t){
    List<Point> matches = new ArrayList<Point>();
    FloatIndexer indexer = m.createIndexer();
    for (int y = 0; y < m.rows(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < m.cols(); x++) {
            if (indexer.get(y,x)>t) {
                System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y +") = "+ indexer.get(y,x));
                matches.add(new Point(x, y));                   
            }
        }           
    }       
    return matches;
}
```

you can just get the first from the list or see how close they are if you expect multiple matches.

Comment: I will try your code with my application and let you know. What parts of the code should I remove (like the for (String hero : getCharacters())). Also, what does the method putText(scaledSrc, hero, point, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, color); ?

Comment: yes this matches multiple templates against a single image, to try and find the best match. the whole project is just a few classes if you have any questions let me know

Comment: Cannot resolve FloatIndexer and OpenCVUtils.matFromJar.

Comment: matfromjar is code form my project that loads an image you don't need that. and i think floatindexer is from javacv. possibly not the same open cv. tyou just need to loop thru all pixels in the result and check the  value.